# Vuetify v-img not using the correct url for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, vuetify.js

I currently have the following code

```
<v-img
   :src="`https://my-s3-bucket-url.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${ item }`"
   class="text-left"
   @click="toggle"
>
```

The item variable is holding the file name stored on s3
When I have non special character, this works just fine. But when I have a file called **PROG-#12ão.jpg** it doesn't work.

I get an 404 error saying the page can't find the file, and it's because the resulting url is in url coded format PROG-#12a%CC%83o.jpg, and this file doesn't exist.

My question is, how do I prevent Vuejs/Vuetify to automatically encode the url?
Thanks in advance

I've tried to generate the full Url and using it directly on the :src but the result was the same

Comment: I would suggest to not use `ã` in the file name, if you can change it.

Comment: I can't control that since it's data coming from external source user. So I need to handle it